# Maintaining row padding during js table search

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-tables

I have a table with information and a simple search function to search any value in said table.

With CSS I styled the table and gave each row `padding`, but when I use the search function it seems to ignore the `padding`.

Maybe the following code snippet is useful:

Try to search for a value that's not there like Pink. Is there a way to maintain the padding throughout the search even if no value is found?

```js
var $rows = $('.list #data');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    
    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

```css
table td:nth-child(1) {
 padding-right: 60px;
 border-left: 1px solid #D3E2E8;
}

table td:nth-child(2) {
 padding-right: 40px;
}

table td:nth-child(3) {
 padding-right: 40px;
}

table td:nth-child(4) {
 padding-right: 50px;
}

table td:nth-child(5) {
 padding-right: 10px;
}

th, td {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #D3E2E8;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #E1F1F7}
tr:hover {background-color: #D0E5ED}

th {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="list">
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Age</th><th>Shirt color</th><th>Favorite food</th></tr>
<tr id="data">
  <td>Brian</td>
  <td>Johnson</td>
  <td>17</td>
  <td>Blue</td>
  <td>Chicken tenders</td>
</tr>
<tr id="data">
  <td>Jessica</td>
  <td>Beloni</td>
  <td>18</td>
  <td>Green</td>
  <td>Pasta Pesto salad</td>
</tr>
<tr id="data">
  <td>Jason</td>
  <td>Popi</td>
  <td>19</td>
  <td>Yellow</td>
  <td>Mac and cheese</td>
</tr>
<tr id="data">
  <td>Daniel</td>
  <td>Soup</td>
  <td>34</td>
  <td>Grey</td>
  <td>Chicken Supreme pizza</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search on any value">
```

Comment: You have to fix `table` and `td` with `css` width property check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `padding` everywhere and replace it with some `width` for your `th` and `td`.

```js
var $rows = $('.list #data');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    
    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

```css
table td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 100px;
    border-left: 1px solid #D3E2E8;
}
table th,
td {
    width: 120px;
}
th,
td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D3E2E8;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #E1F1F7
}
tr:hover {
    background-color: #D0E5ED
}
th {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="list">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Shirt color</th>
        <th>Favorite food</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="data">
        <td>Brian</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
        <td>Chicken tenders</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="data">
        <td>Jessica</td>
        <td>Beloni</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>Green</td>
        <td>Pasta Pesto salad</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="data">
        <td>Jason</td>
        <td>Popi</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>Yellow</td>
        <td>Mac and cheese</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="data">
        <td>Daniel</td>
        <td>Soup</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>Grey</td>
        <td>Chicken Supreme pizza</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search on any value">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $rows = $('.list #data');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    
    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

```css
table{
 width:100%;
}
table td{
width: 20%;
}
table td:nth-child(1) {
 padding-right: 60px;
 border-left: 1px solid #D3E2E8;
}

table td:nth-child(2) {
 padding-right: 40px;
}

table td:nth-child(3) {
 padding-right: 40px;
}

table td:nth-child(4) {
 padding-right: 50px;
}

table td:nth-child(5) {
 padding-right: 10px;
}

th, td {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #D3E2E8;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #E1F1F7}
tr:hover {background-color: #D0E5ED}

th {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="list">
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Age</th><th>Shirt color</th><th>Favorite food</th></tr>
<tr id="data">
  <td>Brian</td>
  <td>Johnson</td>
  <td>17</td>
  <td>Blue</td>
  <td>Chicken tenders</td>
</tr>
<tr id="data">
  <td>Jessica</td>
  <td>Beloni</td>
  <td>18</td>
  <td>Green</td>
  <td>Pasta Pesto salad</td>
</tr>
<tr id="data">
  <td>Jason</td>
  <td>Popi</td>
  <td>19</td>
  <td>Yellow</td>
  <td>Mac and cheese</td>
</tr>
<tr id="data">
  <td>Daniel</td>
  <td>Soup</td>
  <td>34</td>
  <td>Grey</td>
  <td>Chicken Supreme pizza</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search on any value">
```

Comment: Nice try..., But still need to be improve...!!